# Mergesort using apache-spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

**I am new to Apache Spark, I have to write java code for mergesort in apache spark.**

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Merge Sort App");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<Integer> input = sc.parallelize(a); // where a is list of Integers
```

I am done with loading array-list of Integers in `javaRDD<Integer>`:

> I have to use integer element list to sort using megersort with apache spark.

***Any help?***

Comment: why merge-sort? is there a real reason? if not, you can just go with sortBy java function

Comment: If you need to sort your RDD, what about using the standard `sortBy()` method? Here is the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html), where you can find its description.

Comment: In addition, if your list of Integers is small and fits into memory, you can avoid using Spark.

Comment: @AntonioCalì Yes there is a real reason to implement a pure merge sort.

Comment: Well you have your answer, define and create a method with input a JavaRDD and as output a sorted JavaRDD. That's all.

Comment: @AntonOkolnychyi I have big size of dataset which is need to be sorted with merge sort.. approximately with 10 billion. i have tried with 1 billion using threadpool technique with simple java which gives me good result, but it broke when i try to go above in limit. this is the main reason i need to implement it using apache spark.

Comment: @AntonioCalì, i tried but fail to do so, thats why seeking for help from experts.

Comment: Can I suggest a z-sort? To do not fall in a out of memory?

Comment: Can you also tell me its logic? i got this, yes if you have implement this, please help me

Comment: @tabi Honestly, I think that Spark developers did their best to achieve as efficient sorting as they could. So, I would try to use the standard sorting mechanism in Spark. In my view, it will be a hard task to implement something like you mentioned in the description using Spark and you have to be sure you really need this.

Comment: @AntonOkolnychyi i reached at this platform after a decision, i have tried to implement but never successeded till now and i am still on it. Using simple java i have designed a good merge sort with or with out threadpool. and it gave me good result but with limitation of data size. after getting big data set i conclude to use spark to resolve my problem. main thing is to develop merge sort. i will be helpfull if you gave me a way or give me some piece of code that how could i achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function `merge` that takes in two lists of type `Integer` and outputs a single sorted list of `Integer`'s.  Then just call `input.reduce(<classname>::merge)`.

Of course, this depends on you having your RDD hold lists of `Integer`s instead of individual elements.  Think the first part of merge sort where you recurse to the single elements.  You could do this by writing a method `toList` that takes an `Integer` and outputs a `List` with that element in it.  Then you can just do `input.map(<classname>::toList).reduce(<classname>::merge)`.